# How to round a non decimal number to decimal and cast to a Number

Tags: typescript

I am having a number lets say 12 and i have to convert it to 12.0
The variable which will accept this value has type as "Number" so after converting the value to decimal I need to parse it back to number.
I am doing it like this

```
     let var : number = Number(Number.parseFloat(payload.result).toFixed(1));
```

What can I do to parse value as a number and still get the decimal precision.
If i dont use casting I get 12 as 12.0 but its a string and I need the value to be type number

Comment: In js `12 === 12.0`

Answer (score 0):

`12.0`, `12`, `1.2e1` etc are all number literals representing the same value, `12`.

If you want *a number*, then `12` is the exact same as `12.0`, if you want to *display* the number as `12.0` specifically, then you need the string, `'12.0'`, and not the number.